# Firestore NextJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a problem with firestore and Next.JS. I would like to have a list with the ul and li tag of y firetsore document.

I have install firestore and my doc is read by the consol log as you can see in the picture. [image: screenshot of my safari console log]

But as you can see in the same image nothing appear in my web page.

This is the code of my page :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {firebase, db} from '../../src/firebase/index';

class Discoverd extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this. ref = db.collection("Content");
        this.unsubscribe = null;
        this.state = {
            contents : []
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
    }

    onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
        const contents = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const {Category, Name, Description} = doc.data();
        contents.push({
            key: doc.id,
            doc,
            Category,
            Name,
            Description
        });
        })
        console.log(contents);

        this.setState = ({
            contents
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <ul>
                {this.state.contents.map(content => 
                    <li key={content.key}>
                        <h3>{content.Name}</h3>
                    </li>

                )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Discoverd;
```

I don't know where is the problem and how to solve it please help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the state incorrectly.

Try doing this.setState({ contents }), instead of this.setState = ...